# Entity Framework Core: manually changing RowVersion of entity has no effect on concurrency handling

Tags: c#, angular, concurrency, entity-framework-core

I'm having a problem with concurrency. When two users attempt to save the same record one after the other, EF allows them to do so.

My front end is Angular and on the backend I'm using EF Core 7 with a database-first approach.

When both users load the row, it contains a property called `Rv` (`RowVersion`) which is stored as a `byte[]` in the backend and `ArrayBuffer` in the frontend.

Backend in C#:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Rv { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Frontend in Angular:

```
export interface User {
    id: number;
    Rv: ArrayBuffer;
    ...
}
```

When user A updates the row and clicks Save, the backend runs the following code:

Chrome DevTools Shows the following being sent in the Network tab for the RV: "AAAAAAAAEBE="

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Save(User dto)
{
    var entity = await context.Users.FindAsync(id); 
    // Here entity's RowVersion = byte[8] = 0,0,0,0,0,0,16,17

    mapper.Map(dto, entity); // Updates all properties on Entity using AutoMapper
    // Now entity's RowVersion = byte[8] = 0,0,0,0,0,0,16,17

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    // SQL GENERATED: UPDATE [Users] SET LastName = 'ABC' WHERE [Id] = 22 AND [RV] = '0x0000000000001011' 

    // Now entity's RowVersion = byte[8] = 0,0,0,0,0,0,16,18 
}
```

When user B updates the record and clicks Save, the backend runs the following code:

Chrome DevTools Shows the following being sent in the Network tab for the RV: "AAAAAAAAEBE="

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Save(User dto)
{
    var entity = await context.Users.FindAsync(id); 
    // Here entity's RowVersion = byte[8] = 0,0,0,0,0,0,16,18

    mapper.Map(dto, entity); // Updates all properties on Entity using AutoMapper
    // Now entity's RowVersion = byte[8] = 0,0,0,0,0,0,16,17

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    // SQL GENERATED: UPDATE [Users] SET LastName = 'XYZ' WHERE [Id] = 22 AND [RV] = '0x0000000000001012'  

    // Now entity's RowVersion = byte[8] = 0,0,0,0,0,0,16,19
}
```

When running `DbScaffold` to reverse engineer the database, the following Fluent config was added to `DbContext`:

```
entity.Property(e => e.Rv)
      .IsRequired()
      .IsRowVersion()
      .IsConcurrencyToken()
      .HasColumnName("RV");
```

I can see that AutoMapper correctly maps/changes the `Rv` property on the entity to that coming from the DTO (request), but it seems to have no effect on the GENERATED SQL as it does not reflect this change.

Is this the wrong approach to update the `RowVersion` prior to saving in Entity Framework Core?

Shouldn't EF Core detect during `SaveChanges()` that the `RowVersion` was changed and throw a concurrency exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EF Core [Optimistic Concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations#optimistic-concurrency) documentation topic contains the following explanation:

> In EF Core, optimistic concurrency is implemented by configuring a property as a *concurrency* token. The concurrency token is loaded and tracked when an entity is queried - just like any other property. Then, when an update or delete operation is performed during `SaveChanges()`, the value of the concurrency token on the database is compared against the original value read by EF Core.

The most important is that *"the value of the concurrency token on the **database** is compared against the **original** value"*.

This explains the generated `WHERE` conditions you see. However, *"when an entity is queried"* and *"read by EF Core"* are not quite correct, because these are just some of the cases when the **original** value is updated.

EF Core change tracker tracks 2 values of a property - *current* and *original*. *Current* is basically what is the property value of the object. *Original* however is maintained purely inside the change tracker, and is updated with *current* after the entity is read from the database, or after successful update, or can be set manually.

Note that the *original* value must be compared to the database value and not the *current* value, because even if it was read from the database, it is snapshot at the time read query was executed, and the database could have changed after that.

With all that being said, it should be clear that you need to set the **original** value of the concurrency token property (row version in your case) which you send to and receive unmodified from the frontend.

AutoMapper cannot help in this scenario, because what it does is equivalent of the setting the *current* value manually. Also it has no access to the db context metadata/change tracker needed. Also has no way to know (same for EF Core itself) that the value inside the object must be treated as *original*, and all it can do eventually is to ignore it (as EF Core will since `IsRowRomber` implies `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate`).

You are the only one who has that information, so you have to provide it manually to EF Core. It can be done in a several ways, all  requiring access to the change tracker entry for the entity and invoked after setting regular properties and before 'SaveChanges`.

For instance

```cs
context.Entry(entity).OriginalValues.SetValues(new { entity.Rv });
```

or

```cs
context.Entry(entity).OriginalValues[nameof(entity.Rv)] = entity.Rv;
```

or (probably the most natural)

```cs
context.Entry(entity).Property(e => e.Rv).OriginalValue = entity.Rv;
```

or even (when the current value is already set to what is supposed to be the original)

```cs
var rv = context.Entry(entity).Property(e => e.Rv);
rv.OriginalValue = rv.CurrentValue;
```